# How to extract data from embedded plot.ly chart

Tags: python, c#, selenium, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

For example, on this page: https://subredditstats.com/r/notneccesarily

It has a chart with Subscribers, if you click on `Edit in Chart Studio`:
[image]

Then it will go here, which contains the spreadsheet with the data:
[image]

So the question is, given this link: https://subredditstats.com/r/notneccesarily, how would we extract the data (highlighted) from the plot.ly graph?

Comment: Have you done any research? What did you find out?

Comment: @QHarr I found the div id the plot is assigned to is `subscribers-chart-ctn` and a function `createChart` that creates the chart -- but I'm a bit lost beyond that

Comment: tag your binding language ? is it python ?

Comment: @cruisepandey can be python or c#, tagged!